# How to prevent the automatic call of adjacent tab in ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with three tab. Inside the ViewPager i have three fragment. When i launch the first tab i.e the first fragment. Then automatically second tab fragment method is called. How do i resolve this issue. I have used  vpChatType.setOffscreenPageLimit(1); but it does not resolve my issue. Please anyone help me in it. I have stuck in this for 1 day.

i have used this one but does not worked. 
vpChatType.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

Comment: `setOffscreenPageLimit()` should be set to the number of fragments existing in your the `ViewPager`, only use it if you know how many fragments there are going to be in the `ViewPager` . So if you have for example 3 fragments in the `ViewPager` then method called should be `setOffscreenPageLimit(3)`

Comment: yes i  passes 3 but still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to call the method only when the fragment is displayed you can use this in your fragment class :

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser){
        //do whatever you wish when fragment is displayed
    }
}
```

**Hope this helps**

Comment: Where i have to override this?

Comment: in your fragment class